# How can the Moment.js get the timestamp?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the timestamp after manipulating days in [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

I tried use:

```
var a = moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar().getTime()
```

to get the timestamp, but failed.

Comment: get current timestamp?

Comment: I want to get timestamp, not the  date string.

Comment: replace  format('HH:MM:SS') with getTime();

Answer (score 7):

It is not really clear what you mean by "timestamp".

To get the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, use `moment().valueOf();`. This corresponds to JS `Date.getTime();`.

To get the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, use `moment().unix();`.

To get the hour/minute/second as numbers, use `moment().hour();` / `moment().minute();` / `moment().second();`.

To get the ISO 8601 string (recommended for sending data over the wire), use `moment().toISOString();` (e.g. "2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z").

To print a user readable time, use `moment().format();`, e.g. `moment().format('LTS')` will return the localized time including seconds ("8:30:25 PM" for en-Us).

See [moment.js - Display - Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for format specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Classic calendar formatting:

```
const daysBefore = moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar();
```

for unix timestamp (current date minus 10 days):

```
const daysBefore = moment().subtract(10, 'days').unix();
```

Just remember, apply formatting  after subtraction, as formatting returns a string, not momentjs object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment().toDate()`  to get a Javascript `Date` object. Then you can get the timestamp with `getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

> try this one

```
  moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar().format('HH:MM:SS'); //get datetime  
  moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();  // Yesterday at 1:16 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

`calendar` does not have method `getTime()`. You can format your time as follows:

```
let format = 'YYYYMMDD';
let a = moment().subtract(10, 'days').format(format);     
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the timestamp:

`moment().subtract(10, 'days')._d`